# "Cogeodesations" on complete Riemann manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, group-actions, geodesic

Recall that a collineation $\sigma$ on a real affine/projective space is a self-bijection of the space which preserves lines (as sets of points) of the space. Considering that geodesics are a natural extension of "lines" on Riemann manifolds of dimension $\ge 2$, a "cogeodesation" $\tau$ on a complete Riemann manifold can be similarly defined to be a bijection of the manifold which preserves geodesics (as sets of points).

**Question**:

$1$: The weaker line-keeping property of $\sigma$ will lead to its stronger linear-mapping nature. Does $\tau$ have a similar property, that we can deduce its **smoothness** (thus a [projective automorphism](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1021041802041.pdf)) from its geodesic-preserving property?

$2$: A seemingly weaker but equivalent definition for a collineation $\sigma$ is that $\sigma$ maps any $3$ collinear points to $3$ still collinear points. Do we get the same set of cogeodesations (no need to be smooth if the answer to question $1$ is negative) if we loose the definition to 'mapping any $3$ cogeodesic points to $3$ still cogeodesic points'?

Comment: [This answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/338080) addresses the special case of constant-curvature model spaces, including hyperbolic spaces.

Comment: @Kajelad Your reference settled the smooth case, but is there any proof on the smoothness of cogeodesations on $\Bbb{H}^n$?

Comment: You should decide if you want to preserve parameterized or un- parameterized geodesics. The resulting maps are called affine or projective and are well- studied.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I know affine maps, but I didn't find out what you said 'projective maps' are. I also don't define my map to be smooth (meaning you can't use differential methods) - in fact I want to prove it.

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean by "preserving geodesics". As I said, there are two notions: You can assume that for every geodesic $c: [a,b]\to M$, the composition $f\circ c$ is again a geodesic. (In the smooth setting, such maps are called **affine** in differential geometry.) Or, you can assume that for every geodesic $\gamma\subset M$, regarded as a subset, $f(\gamma)$ is again geodesic (regarded as a subset). Such maps are called **projective.**

Comment: Lastly, if you just care about the hyperbolic space, then the only self-bijections which send geodesics to geodesics as sets are hyperbolic isometries. This is essentially due to von Staudt.